# h2o not working while knitting markdown file in R

Tags: r-markdown, h2o

I am running h2o in R (using RMarkdown) and it is working fine when I run the chunks one at a time. However, when I try to knit the HTML file, it gives me an error as follows:

> Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix, : Unexpected CURL error: Could not resolve host: localhost

Anyone know how to fix this? My code chunk is as follows:

```
if (try.h2o == TRUE){
  h2o.init()
  h2o.removeAll()

  train.data.h2o <- as.h2o(train.data)
  h2o.describe(train.data.h2o)

  tic("\n\n\nTotal Time taken by H20 Auto ML to train: ")
  aml <- h2o.automl(y = label.names, 
                    training_frame = train.data.h2o,
                    max_models = 50,
                    seed = 1,
                    project_name = "temp")
  toc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if I kill the Java process running in the background and re-knot the Markdown, it works fine, so this might have been a temporary issue.